# How to create a command shortcut in BASH or ZSHRC shells?

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I know how to create an `alias` or a `PATH` however those are both used to navigate folders.

How would you create a shortcut to say quickly type the following commands every time?

**alog** = `tail -f /var/log/apache2/error_log`

**arestart** = `sudo apachectl restart`

So a shortcut similar to how `git` and `svn` commands work

Comment: What's wrong in creating a bash script?

Comment: In bash: `alias alog='tail -f /var/log/apache2/error_log'`

Comment: Bash `alias` is not only to navigate folders, you can create whatever you want, that is for. So what's wrong with: `alias arestart ='sudo apachectl restart'`?

Comment: You guys are right, I thought `alias` was only to navigate with `cd` in front.. do you want to post the answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It isn't true that `alias` is used only to navigate folders. It can be used for other commands as well (that's why it's called `alias`).

In example:

```
alias arestart='sudo apachectl restart'
alias alog='tail -f /var/log/apache2/error_log'
```

and place them in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`.

Or you may want to put all your alias definitions into a separate file like
`~/.bash_aliases` (check bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package for details). And you can include alias definition in your `~/.bashrc` as follow:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

Alternatively you can use bash functions which works similar to aliases (which supports arguments). For example:

```
# Restart apache
# Usage: arestart
arestart() {
  sudo apachectl restart
}

# Show log via tail.
# Usage: alog (file)
alog() {
  tail -f "$1"
}

# Find file
# Usage: ff (file)
ff() {
  find . -name "$1"
}

# Search in command history.
# Usage: hs (string)
hs() {
  history | grep "$1"
}
```

Comment: You have to quote all those `$1` -- `hs() { history | grep "$1"; }` -- otherwise the argument is subject to word splitting and filename expansion: for example `hs "foo bar"` results in `grep: bar: No such file or directory`  (see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions)